# Passing multiple model using Ajax returns null?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using a model that contains multiple models. I am also using AJAX request to send data to an action. The parameter of the action contains model type that contains multiple models. I am getting null for each sub model within the main model. How can I fix this.
Models:

```
public class MainModel
{
  public SubModel1 sub1 {get;set;}
  public SubModel2 sub2 {get;set;}
}
```

Please note SubModel1 and SubModel2 contains properties as follows: 1.Id, Name. 2. Id, Location.
Controller

```
public ActionResult PostData(MainModel main)
{
return View();
}
```

View:

```
@model project.Models.MainModel
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostData", "ControllerMain",
                    new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                        HttpMethod = "POST",
                    }))
                    {
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub1.Id, new { @Value = "1"})
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub1.Name, new { @Value = "user1"})
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub2.Id, new { @Value = "1"})
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub2.Location, new { @Value = "UK"})
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveData">Save</button>
                    }
```

When I inspect main using the debugger I get the value of both models as null. How can I fix this. The following might be useful if I change the parameter of PostData to SubModel1, or SubModel2 I do get the data but this is not the case because I would like to get data of a multiple model.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your model as below:**

```
public class MainModel
{
    public MainModel()
    {
        sub1 = new SubModel1();
        sub2 = new SubModel2();
    }
    public SubModel1 sub1 { get; set; }
    public SubModel2 sub2 { get; set; }
}
```

**Your Controller should be like this:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult PostData()
    {
        return View(new MainModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostData(MainModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**And View:**

```
@model project.Models.MainModel@using (
Ajax.BeginForm("PostData", "Home",
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
    }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub1.Id, new { @Value = "1"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub1.Name, new { @Value = "user1"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub2.Id, new { @Value = "1"})
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.sub2.Location, new { @Value = "UK"})
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SaveData">Save</button>
    }
```